# MySQL: keep always the same value in two fields of different tables

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to keep always the same value in two fields of different tables?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about the nature of this problem and why you want to do this? The "best" solution might depend on it...

Answer (score 1):

You could use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) so that if one of the fields is change, the other is synchronized to match.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually best not to store a value twice. Instead you can store the value in just one of the tables and when you query you can join the two tables together on a foreign key so that you have access to values from both tables at the same time:

```
SELECT table1.foo, table2.bar
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.table2_id = table2.id
```

If you store the value twice it is called denormalization. This can lead to problems if the values ever get out-of-sync for one reason or another. Sometimes it is advantageous to denormalize to improve performance, but a single join is very fast so unless you have measured the performance and found it to be too slow, I'd advise against doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you couldn't `normalize` the design of your database so that you don't have the same data twice and don't have to worry about stuff like this anymore?

In case you can't change the design take a look at [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: My guess is the values that are kept identical are user-entered free-form text or soemthing, but then he could have a table for it and reference the new entries by ID.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you ever want to do this?

If one attribute of one entity is *always* the same as some attribute of another related entity, then you have a redundant data model.

Instead of trying to *synchronize* the attributes, *refer* to one attribute. Use a join to join the first table to the second, then get the value of the attribute from one table. E.g, if you currently have this:

```
 TableA.foo should always equal TableB.bar
```

drop column TableA.foo, and do this:

```
 select A.*, B.bar as foo
 from TableA A 
 join TableB B on (B.foreign_key = A.key);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE A (FieldInA) VALUES ('X')
INSERT INTO TABLE B (FieldInB) VALUES ('X')
```

Then simply never delete, nor update, these table rows, and voilà, you have always the same value in two fields of different tables.

Comment: Wasn't me, but it's a gamble.  If you delete this answer, you'll get the rep back when there's a recalculation of rep.